# путь к картинке во vue <scripts>

Tags: vue.js

День добрый!
как правильно указывать путь к картинке в тэге  во Vue компоненте.
Если я указываю url в template или style, то в последствии, после npm run build путь становится относительным и всё работает, но если я вычисляю путь в script то он не становится относительным (((
Пример :

```
<template>
<div class='header-zone'>
    <img class="header-logo_img" src="../assets/top_logo_hcb_name.png" />
    <img class="header-profile_img" v-bind:src="getCurUserPhoto()"  />
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data: function () {
    return {
        no_profile_url: '../assets/3.svg',
        curUserData: {
            id : 1231231231231,
            fullname: 'werwer',
            profile_url: ""
        },
    }
},
methods: {
    getCurUserPhoto: function () {
        return this.curUserData.profile_url === '' ? this.no_profile_url : this.curUserData.profile_url
    }
}
```

}

при этом идентичный путь к первой картинке обрабатывается корректно.

У меня получилось сделать через import, но хотелось бы узнать правильное решение.
Рабочий вариант через import

```
<script>
import image from '../assets/3.svg'
export default {
data: function () {
    return {
        no_profile_url: image,
        curUserData: {
            id : 1231231231231,
            fullname: 'werwer',
            profile_url: ""
        },
    }
},
methods: {
    getCurUserPhoto: function () {
        return this.curUserData.profile_url === '' ? this.no_profile_url : this.curUserData.profile_url
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Правильный вариант (если это еще актуально):

```js
<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
        no_profile_url: require('../assets/3.svg'), 
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

В этом случае, строку с url можно формировать любым удобным способом.